# Is it necessary to perform API if-else check when using AppCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

Previously, I'm using SherlockActionBar library. The following code will work, across Android 2.3 till Android 5.

```
this.searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
```

However, after migrating to AppCompat, we need to migrate to the following code

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(JStockFragmentActivity.this.searchMenuItem);
```

When I look at the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView, it states that

> On API level 11 or higher
>
> Get the action view by calling getActionView() on the corresponding
>   MenuItem:
>
> ```
> menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView()
> ```

I was wondering, is it necessary that I need to write my migrated code in the following way?

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    this.searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
} else {
    MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(this.searchMenuItem);
}
```

Comment: This is an MenuItemCompat function. It provides backwards compatible functionality. Your if statement is not necessary.